# getting this.props in componentDidMount() or some other way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class UserExperience extends Component<
  UserExperienceProps,
  UserExperienceState
> {
  state: UserExperienceState = {
    Experience: 0,
  };

  constructor(props: UserExperienceProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Experience: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`apiProfile?name=${this.props.name}&auth=${this.props.auth}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response[0] !== undefined) this.setState({ Experience: response[0].Experience });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { Experience } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} className="text-yellow-400 mr-1" />
        {Experience} <span className="font-semibold">EXP</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So I am trying to grab `this.props` so I can call `fetch` for my API. However `this.props.name` and `this.props.auth` returns as undefined.

However if I do `console.log(this.props.name)` and `console.log(this.props.auth)` in `render()` then it shows up but from my understanding you can't simply do `fetch` inside of render() as that's not its intended design.

When I searched up I know some people mentioned `bind`ing the method, but I guess I'm not too familiar on what that's supposed to do. And a lot of the other solutions found are utilizing `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` which is obviously now heading its way for deprecation.

Comment: It looks that your issue comes from how `name` and `auth` are defined/fetched. `componentDidMount` runs only once, and if initial values for `name` and `auth` are undefined it will render undefined. `render` however runs at mounting and on every update. so if props values are updated from undefined values to a proper expected value, then render will print undefined first then on update prints your expected props value

Comment: @buzatto `<UserExperience name={userData.userName} auth={userData.userAuthId} />` is how it's being called originally. And the data being called here is valid and does exist. It returns the userName and the userAuthId which is from OAUTH

Comment: `userData` values are hardcoded at your code or you fetch them in an async call through oauth?

Comment: Fetched through session which is unpacked after JWT validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, your issue here is because at mount your userData is not retrieved yet since it's a async call. once it's fetched, you receive the expected props value but `didMount` doesnt run again. you should use `componentDidUpdate` for that. you need to use also some validation condition to verify if `prevProps` are different from `this.props`, otherwise you will face on a infinite loop.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.name === this.props.name) return
    fetch(`apiProfile?name=${this.props.name}&auth=${this.props.auth}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        if (response[0] !== undefined) this.setState({ Experience: response[0].Experience });
      });
  }
```

another approach would be at parent validate the existence of `name` (and/or auth) in order to render UserExperience (if you want to render that component only when you have fetched its values) like:

```
{ userData.name && <UserExperience name={userData.userName} auth={userData.userAuthId} /> }
```

in this way mount will be executed correctly since `UserExperience` will only be rendered when the values are at your disposal.